# how to show or hide spinner according to ajax response in ember.js controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I had set an emberjs action for a button so that, whenever a user clicks that button I need to navigate the user to a new page. Before doing transition I need to make several api calls and based on the results of api calls I will transition user to a new page. I have no issues with transitions based on results but I cannot show a spinner image during these api calls.

In the example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punex/1) I used setTimeout method to delay the transition as I cannot expose the api. In that I could see the console logs are printed in order; but I cant see the spinner during the timeout. Any help will be appreciated regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your provided example you call `hideSpinner` after calling `setTimeout` which is preceded by a call to your `showSpinner` function. Since executing those 3 function calls takes a very small amount of time, you couldn't even notice the spinner showing up, because the spinner is hidden again almost instantaneously.

What you need to do is call `hideSpinner` in your callback function, right after you call `transitionToRoute` on your controller.

**EDIT**
Based on @buuda's suggestion and your [new example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punex/2/edit), I've come up with [this](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nehobelo/2/edit).

This basically does what @buuda says, create a promise object that will be resolved/rejected based on the AJAX call, and store that object into an array, and pass that array into `Ember.RSVP.all()`.

Comment: thank you both Kemal and buuda. I understood what buuda advised from Kemal's example. helpful one. And also got that, when I put `async: false` inside ajax call which is inside the promise, first ajax call takes its own time to get response and meanwhile spinner is not shown. Its due to promise and ajax calls takes separate time to get their work done in my knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

Use [RSVP Promises](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/) to wait for all API queries to finish:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    'goToFoo': function(){
      var Indexcontroller = this;
      showSpinner();

      Ember.RSVP.all(promisesArray).then(function(resultsArray) {
         hideSpinner();
         Indexcontroller.transitionToRoute('foo');
      }, function(error) {
         ...handle errors
      });
    }
  }
});
```

An ajax request will return a promise, so you can batch them in an array and pass that to the RSVP.all method. The resultsArray will contain the results of every ajax call, in order. The error function will be invoked if any response generates an error.

Comment: @buuda & Kemal: thanks for your answer regarding my question. Here is an [updated jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/punex/2/edit) in which I used a sample api call which will result in error. however I looped it to make some delay. And you can see that the spinner is not visible during these api calls. Could you please guide me in this RSVP as I cannot get it done by myself after a long struggle.? ..

Comment: Promises need to be resolved or rejected. jQuery ajax call returns a promise. You can push these to an array and then pass the array to Ember.RSVP.all() as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with jquery. Maybe hiding elements on screen and showing loading indicator when doing those api calls?

```
$("loading_indicator").show()
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    success: function(xhr,test){
        $("loading_indicator").hide()
    }
})
```

Comment: I had tried it already, James. Not only inside success callback but also in **beforeSend()** and **complete()** functions of ajax call to show and hide the spinner..that didn't help me. :(